# Why is the Wikipedia API not returning summary of requested page (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, wikipedia-api

I am currently trying to create a file in which a user enters a search query and it returns the wikipedia summary page of the search query; using the code below:

```
import wikipedia

input = input("Question: ")

print (wikipedia.summary(input))
```

When I execute the code into Windows Powershell as shown below.

```
PS C:\Users\Samue\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Python\Pyva> python wipedia.py
Question: Wales
```

It outputs correctly as expected and allows you to enter a search query but then after entering the search query, a new blank line appears with the blinking cursor block and no summary is returned.

Although, when I `import wikipedia` on PS and enter `print(wikipedia.summary("Wales"))`, the summary page returns with no problem.

Any help is appreciated
(I'm using Python 3.8.2)

Comment: Could not reproduce. Your code does print the summary after some time. How long did you wait for the result?

Comment: Unrelated: don't use inbuilt function names like `input` as variable names

Comment: `input` is a method in Python. You cannot use it as a variable name. Try naming it `_input` or something more meaningful like, `search_query` or something like that

Comment: @Filip you __can__ use `input` as a variable name but it can cause unexpected bahaviour since it shadows the built-in function name

Comment: @rdas I've been waiting for the result for well over 15 minutes and I'm still waiting and I'll make sure to give the variable a more sensible name in the future

Comment: @rdas Yeah, it can cause unexpected behaviour. Like this exact post.

Comment: @Filip Since I have run the code posted by OP I can certify that the naming thing is definitely not causing the issue that OP is facing.

Comment: @Saojon123 sounds weird. Try running the script through a debugger and check where it is stuck

Comment: @rdas I debugged it, and it appears to be stuck at the 'print (wikipedia.summary(input))' line. I tested it on an online IDE and the code works, so maybe it's the IDE I'm using is the problem? (I'm using Atom).

Comment: You'll need to step into the `summary()` function and figure out which line in the library code it's stuck in

Comment: Your firewall or antivirus might block web requests from one interpreter but not from a different one.

Comment: Thank you Tgr, that seems to be exactly it! I disabled the Comodo firewall and now it's working like a charm!